# Python script to warm AWS lambda for cold start problem

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cold-start

I followed the lambda-warmer https://github.com/jeremydaly/lambda-warmer for NodeJS to create a similar script for python:

- Warm the lambda function every a few minutes
- Warm more than one lambda functions if I set up the concurrency parameters

Here is my python code:
https://github.com/pafun/lambda-warmer-python/blob/master/lambda-warmer-python.py

Here is a typical input:

```
{
    "flag": "warmer", 
    "concurrency": 10,
    "test": false,
    "delay": 300
}
```

Usually, the script won't warm up the exact number of instances for me unless I increase the delay time. Like the above example input, I usually get 6-8 Concurrent Executions as I observed in lambda AWS monitor.

**How can I make sure the exact number of lambda instances will be warmed?**